# Bootstrap problems when resizing my browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've found some problems in a template I've done with Bootstrap, and I'm almost crazy on finding what's happening with this strange behaviour. Can you help me make this site present exactly as is seen in a mobile phone when I resize my browser? I think I lack something...

The website is http://www.joanraga.com/blog, when you open it in a mobile browser it fits nicely, all responsive and good. When you open it in a computer browser, it does as well, but when you resize the browser it looks like somebody fooled my CSS. If you use the adaptative view on Firefox, it shows nicely as well.

I'll post here some pics about how it's supossed to be seen:

Tablet mode, nice
[image: tablet mode, nice]

Phone mode, nice

[image: phone mode, nice]

Resized browser, all f&%$*d up
[image: resized browser, all f&%$*d up]

Comment: checking your page it seems that you have defined as min width 992 px, that's why you are seeing that behaviour: @media (min-device-width: 992px)

Comment: @GenaroMorales you were kinda right. I used min-device-width and I had to use min-width instead. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, let me post it as an aswer to let you close the question. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checking your page it seems that you have defined as min width 992 px, that's why you are seeing that behaviour: `@media (min-device-width: 992px)` use min-width instead.

Comment: You're very right, I didn't see that I had a fixed width in that media query! thank you!